# Delphi 10.4 and INDY 9

Tags: delphi, updates, porting, installation-package, indy-9

I have a lot of programs that use INDY 9 in BDS2007.
I'm porting them to Delphi 10.4 but here there is INDY 10.

It is possible to remove INDY 10 (unused at moment) and install/compile INDY 9 in Delphi 10.4?
Before making mistakes I ask if someone already made that with success.

Best regards
Silverio

Comment: I strongly suggest to NOT replace `Indy 10` with `Indy 9`! `Indy 10` includes latest features and standards updates.

Comment: Is Indy 9 compatible with Unicode string type introduced with Delphi 2009 (I don't think so!)? Be prepared for a lot of trouble, crazy side effects or even compilation errors if you try to use such an outdated version with current IDE versions.

Comment: @DelphiCoder No, Indy 9 is not compatible with Unicode at all.

Answer (score 1):

Indy 9 is NOT compatible with IDE/compiler versions after BDS 2007.  Beyond that, you MUST upgrade to Indy 10.  Everything you can do in Indy 9 can be done in Indy 10, though the syntax may be slightly different, depending on what functionality you are using exactly.

Comment: Thanks Remy
Actually, I use ReadFromStream, not available in Indy10, to get not-blocking access to the incoming buffer. The sender sends a continuous frame of packets delimited by a packet Head ({) and a packet tail (}) encoded ASCII85:

paste.ofcode.org/Ap5CYv5wndHvWXnG5HW39Y'

Comment: *"I use `ReadFromStream`, not available in Indy10*" - yes, it is. Most of the reading/writing methods of `TIdTCPConnection` in Indy 9 were moved to `TIdIOHandler` in Indy 10. So instead of doing `Client.ReadStream(...)`, you would now do `Client.IOHandler.ReadStream(...)`. Likewise, the `TIdTCPConnection.InputBuffer` was also moved to `TIdIOHandler`. That being said, the code you linked to can be rewritten in Indy 10 using the `InputBuffer.IndexOf()`, `InputBuffer.Remove()`/`IOHandler.Discard()`, and `InputBuffer.ExtractTo...(...)` methods.